# boost split recursively and append to set

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have a set of strings separated by #. I want to split them and insert into unordered_set.

For example.

abc#def#ghi
xyz#mno#pqr

I use boost split by passing unordered set. But everytime I get new result set. I want to append the next result into the same set.

```
std::string str1 =  "abc#def#ghi";
std::string str2 = "xyz#mno#pqr";
std::unordered_set<std::string> result
boost::split(result, str1, boost::is_any_of("#"));
boost::split(result, str2, boost::is_any_of("#"));
```

If i check result set, i only get xyz, mno, pqr. I want it to have been appended with "abc def and ghi". How to achieve it.

Note: I dont want to use a any additional container.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do: (see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e6d0ca7d16d6a94)**)

```
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> result;

    std::istringstream iss("abc#def#ghi");

    std::string tok;
    while (std::getline(iss, tok, '#'))
         result.insert(tok);

    iss.str("xyz#mno#pqr");
    iss.clear();

    while (std::getline(iss, tok, '#'))
         result.insert(tok);

    for (auto& s : result)
        std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Comment: would this be faster than boost::split?

Answer (score 2):

This is because `boost::split` clean the destination container before writing into it.

I'd use `boost::tokenizer` for what you want.

```
#include<boost/tokenizer>

// ....

typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;
boost::char_separator<char> sep("#");

std::string str1 =  "abc#def#ghi";
std::string str2 = "xyz#mno#pqr";

std::unordered_set<std::string> result;

tokenizer t1(str1, sep), t2(str2, sep);

std::copy(t1.begin(), t1.end(), std::inserter(result, result.end()) );
std::copy(t2.begin(), t2.end(), std::inserter(result, result.end()) );
```